# Toolkit phonetextbox's actionicon to align at left side

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, toolkit

I have a textbox with ActionIcon,by default it's positioning at right side of the textbox. how can i make the ActionIcon to Leftside of the textbox.

This is my code,

```
<ToolKit:PhoneTextBox Grid.Row="2"  Hint="Search Location . . ." ActionIcon="/Images/searchlocation.png"  BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" x:Name="myTxtbx" Background="{StaticResource ContentBackground}" KeyUp="myTxtbx_KeyUp"></ToolKit:PhoneTextBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <Grid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="toolkit:PhoneTextBox">
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxBrush}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxForegroundBrush}"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxBrush}"/>
                    <Setter Property="SelectionBackground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
                    <Setter Property="SelectionForeground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxSelectionForegroundBrush}"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBorderThickness}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBorderThickness}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="toolkit:PhoneTextBox">
                                <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="Transparent">
                                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="HintBorder">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                                <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="TextBorder">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="TextBorder">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" Storyboard.TargetName="TextBorder">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="HorizontalAlignment" Storyboard.TargetName="Text">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                                <HorizontalAlignment>Stretch</HorizontalAlignment>
                                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="HintBorder">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxEditBackgroundBrush}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="HintBorder">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxEditBorderBrush}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="LengthIndicatorStates">
                                            <VisualState x:Name="LengthIndicatorVisible">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="LengthIndicator">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="0, 0, 0, 27"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="LengthIndicator">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="0.6"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.350" To="32" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="LengthIndicator">
                                                        <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                                            <ExponentialEase Exponent="6"/>
                                                        </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                                    </DoubleAnimation>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="LengthIndicatorHidden">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.350" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="LengthIndicator">
                                                        <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                                            <ExponentialEase Exponent="6"/>
                                                        </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                                    </DoubleAnimation>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="0, 0, 0, 0"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="LengthIndicator">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.350" Value="0"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="LengthIndicator">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.350">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                                <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <Border x:Name="LengthIndicatorBorder">
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="LengthIndicator" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneContrastBackgroundBrush}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneMargin}" Opacity="0" TextAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                                            <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                                                <TranslateTransform/>
                                            </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                                        </TextBlock>
                                    </Border>
                                    <Border x:Name="HintBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}">
                                        <Grid>
                                            <ContentControl x:Name="HintContent" Background="Transparent" Content="{TemplateBinding Hint}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="3,0,3,0" Style="{TemplateBinding HintStyle}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ActualHintVisibility}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                            <ContentControl x:Name="ContentElement" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxInnerMargin}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Border>
                                    <Border x:Name="TextBorder" BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="Transparent" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}" Visibility="Collapsed">
                                        <TextBox x:Name="Text" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" FontStyle="{TemplateBinding FontStyle}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" SelectionForeground="{TemplateBinding SelectionForeground}" SelectionBackground="{TemplateBinding SelectionBackground}" TextAlignment="{TemplateBinding TextAlignment}" TextWrapping="{TemplateBinding TextWrapping}" Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"/>
                                    </Border>
                                    <Border x:Name="ActionIconBorder" Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="72" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="84">
                                        <Image x:Name="ActionIcon" Height="26" Source="{TemplateBinding ActionIcon}" Width="26"/>
                                    </Border>
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="MeasurementTextBlock" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" FontStyle="{TemplateBinding FontStyle}" FontStretch="{TemplateBinding FontStretch}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="8" Opacity="0" TextAlignment="{TemplateBinding TextAlignment}" TextWrapping="{TemplateBinding TextWrapping}" Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </Grid.Resources>
            <StackPanel>
                <toolkit:PhoneTextBox ActionIcon="/Assets/ApplicationIcon.png"></toolkit:PhoneTextBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
```

[image: Sample ScreenShot]

Comment: Thank you very much sir... this what i'm searching a lot